# Angular CLI 6: Unknown option: '--locale'

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Running `ng serve` with a custom locale data as the docs explain (https://next.angular.io/guide/i18n)  in the new Angular 6, I'm getting this error:

```
Unknown option: '--locale'
```

The same is happening with `delete-output-path` and `named-chunks`. How can we set this flags now?

Comment: Might be related to this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10532

Comment: There is an open ticket: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11039 - ng serve is missing i18n related options

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As part of introducing [CLI Workspaces](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace), the developers have removed build-related command line switches in favor of configuring them inside the new `angular.json` file.
After some digging into the new schema (available at the link above), the easiest way to reintroduce your localization switches would be to add them under the following path inside `angular.json`:  *projects/your-project/architect/build/options*.

Then serve your app without any switches: `ng serve`.

In the long term, I suppose you are encouraged to define yourself different configurations and set those options over there. Again, see the schema for more about this.

Here is an example of what I did:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my-app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "i18nFile": "src/locale/messages.some-lang.xlf",
            "i18nLocale": "some-lang",
            "i18nFormat": "xlf",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [ ...
            ],
            "styles": [ ...
...
```

### Update

Apparently there is a [PR for the documentation update](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/23660), which explains how to do it (pretty much how I wrote it here ;-) )

Comment: Wow, someone actually took the time to downvote this now, even though this is an answer to a version two years ago so it may not be applicable anymore..  what's with you people :)

Answer (score 11):

For the record, `--locale` was also removed from `ng build` but they introduced instead `--i18n-locale` as specified in [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/i18n).

E.g, you can do:

`ng build --prod --i18n-locale de --i18n-format xlf --i18n-file src/locale/messages.de.xlf`

Unfortunately, this does not work with `ng serve`.

Comment: --prod won't work because of the introduction of cli workspaces: use configurations instead ([how to do x with angular-cli v6](https://medium.com/@beeman/how-to-do-x-in-angular-cli-v6-db7530c23066)).

Answer (score 0):

With Angular 9, none of the above answers work (for `ng serve` at least). Here's how to do it:

Open `angular.json` file, go to `architect -> build -> options` section. Add the option `"i18nLocale": "pt"` for `pt` locale. This sets the default local of your app to `pt`.